# Windows Comfort Mouse 4500 Configuration

Tags: drivers, windows, mouse, microsoft

I just installed Ubuntu after a long break and long hardship with windows 7 and I was wondering if anyone could answer my question of how to configure my two extra buttons on my Microsoft Comfort Mouse 4500?

On windows I normally used [Microsoft Intellipoint](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/d/comfort-mouse-4500).

Please and thank you for your time :)

using `xev | grep button` I get:

`state 0x10, button 1, same_screen YES

    state 0x110, button 1, same_screen YES

    state 0x10, button 6, same_screen YES

    state 0x10, button 6, same_screen YES

    state 0x10, button 6, same_screen YES

    state 0x10, button 6, same_screen YES

    state 0x10, button 5, same_screen YES

    state 0x1010, button 5, same_screen YES

    state 0x10, button 3, same_screen YES

    state 0x410, button 3, same_screen YES

    state 0x10, button 9, same_screen YES

    state 0x10, button 9, same_screen YES

    state 0x10, button 8, same_screen YES

    state 0x10, button 8, same_screen YES`

I'd like to assign button 9 to do a middle click, as the middle clicking on my mouse doesn't function properly.

Comment: Okay, so far my answer works, its just a problem with your mouse button 2 not working.  Does `xev` give any output for your middle mouse button (button 2)?

Comment: Seth, this is what I get when I middle click with xev:

KeymapNotify event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  101 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
ButtonRelease event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x165, subw 0x4600002, time 4633500, (27,10), root:(1768,525),
    state 0x210, button 2, same_screen YES

Comment: hmm, interesting.. I can't think of why this isn't working top of my head.  I'll let you know if I can think of anything.  If your middle mouse button doesn't work, I suggest asking a new question about it, as that is another topic of itself.

Answer (score 0):

## Install:

We will need `xbindkeys` and `xte` to do this. Install them by running:

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xautomation
```

## Bind:

Now the fun starts!
Before we start binding our mouse buttons to actions we need to create a configuration file for `xbindkeys`.  Run:

```
touch .xbindkeysrc && xbindkeys -f .xbindkeysrc  && gedit .xbindkeysrc
```

This command creates the file and opens it for editing.  Add this to the bottom of the file:

```
"xte 'mouseclick 2'"
b:9
```

Save the file.

Restart the computer.

**NOTE:** If you tell me what you want the other buttons to do I will add the commands for that.

Comment: Personally I would like one button to minimize everything and another to do expose.

Comment: BTW are these instructions for unity? because I can't find "startup applications" in gnome-shell :(

Comment: @Ghost You want to hide all Windows and the un-hide them?  I think I can do that.  I'll look into the Gnome Shell thing.